# Using WatiN ... check if an element exists?

Tags: c#, watin

I'm using WatiN to write an automated bot for harvesting information. Is it possible to check if an element on the page exists?

Comment: I'm not familiar with WatiN, but what does the `Find.ByName` method returns when the element doesn't exist? If it returns `null` or something like that, than that's probably all you need to know...?

Comment: I tried to display the result with a .ToString() and a MessageBox.Show(), and then inputted a fake element id and it didn't show a null. It showed a message like "searching for element with id x"

Answer (score 7):

I usually the use the following:

```
WatiN.Core.IE window = new WatiN.Core.IE();
if (window.Elements.Exists("yourElementId")) {
// do whatever
}
```